# $cl_f(A)=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-writing

Given a subset $A \subseteq B$, the closure of $A$ under $f$, denoted by $cl_f(A)$, is the smallest subset of $B$ which contains $A$ and is closed under $f$.

Define a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of subsets of B recursively as follows:

$$A_0 = A$$
$$A_{n+1}=f[A_n]\cup A_n \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Prove $cl_f(A)=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$.

How do I go about this proof? I am having trouble starting it.

Comment: What is $f$, a continuous function?

Comment: @Dunham $f$ can be any function at all (and $A, B$ any sets with $A\subseteq B$), the statement remains true.

Comment: This is a repost: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629162/prove-cl-fa-bigcup-n-in-mathbbna-n. Please don't do that - edit the original question rather than asking it again in a slightly modified form.

Comment: The duplicate marking on this question is the wrong way round. The other question is closed because this one has answers.

Answer (score 0):

$cl_f(A)\subset\cup_nA_n$ since $\cup_nA_n$ it contains $A$ and is stable by $f$.

On the other hand, suppose that $A_n\subset cl_f(A)$, $f(A_n)=A_{n+1}\subset cl_f(A)$, since $A_0=A\subset cl_f(A)$, this implies recursively that $\cup_nA_n\subset cl_f(A)$.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show two things:

- $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ is closed under $f$.
- Every set containing $A$ closed under $f$ contains $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

For the second one, try proof by induction. Do you see why every set containing $A$ which is closed under $f$ must contain $A_0$? OK, now supposing every set containing $A$ which is closed under $f$ must contain $A_n$, do you see how to show that every set containing $A$ which is closed under $f$ must contain $A_{n+1}$?

For the first, suppose $a\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$. You want to show that $f(a)$ is also in $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$. Well, if something is in a union of sets, then it's in one of the sets in the union - so $a\in A_n$ for some $n$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Writing $C = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$, it suffices to prove:

- $C$ contains $A$ and is closed under $f$; and
- $C$ is a subset of all other $f$-closed subsets containing $A$.

Clearly $C$ contains $A$. To prove that $C$ is closed under $f$ note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in A_n$, you have $f(x) \in A_{n+1}$.

To prove that $C$ is a subset of all other $f$-closed subsets containing $A$, let $C'$ be such a subset and prove (e.g. by induction) that $A_n \subseteq C'$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.