# Iterative function on set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a name for the procedure/function $ S = f(A) $ such that:

$$ S = \{ x : x \in A \} \cup \{ f(x) : x \in S \} $$

Basically take a set, apply a function to all it's elements, if you get any new elements, apply the function to those elements again etc.

Comment: In some contexts what you are looking for would be called the _least fixed point_ of the function $F$ that takes a set $T$ and yields $T\cup f[T]$, and would be written $\operatorname{fix} F A$ or $(\operatorname{fix} F)(A)$ or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) operation. Coincidentally, there was a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629993/19542) asked earlier today about such things.

Given a set $S$ and a function $f : S \to S$, the *closure* of a subset $A \subseteq X$ is a subset $\mathrm{cl}_f(A) \subseteq S$ such that the following three conditions hold:

- $A \subseteq \mathrm{cl}_f(A)$;
- For all $x \in S$, if $x \in \mathrm{cl}_f(A)$, then $f(x) \in \mathrm{cl}_f(A)$; and
- If $C \subseteq S$ is any subset such that $A \subseteq C$ and $f(x) \in C$ for all $x \in C$, then $\mathrm{cl}_f(A) \subseteq C$.

The first two conditions say that $\mathrm{cl}_f(A)$ contains $A$ and contains $f$ of all of its elements; the third condition says that $\mathrm{cl}_f(A)$ is the smallest such subset.